# Pegar valores de um formulário usando um model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model

Estou criando um formulário web e já me falaram aqui no SOpt pra eu usar um model, já que estou usando o .Net Core Razor. Estou tentando criar o model, para passar de parâmetro mas não consigo recuperar os valores dos campos, já que estou tentando usar uma List de strings. Vou deixar +/- como estou fazendo aí abaixo pra vocês conseguirem me dar uma ajuda nisso aí, sou novo na tecnologia. Obrigado.

**OBS:** Os meus campos estão sendo gerados automaticamente, então os id's, name's, estão bem parecidos, como `checkbox0`, `checkbox1`, `checkbox2`...

**MODEL:**

```
public class cl{
    public List<string> checkbox { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

**OnPost da página:**

```
public IActionResult OnPost(cl c)
{
    var teste = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        c.checkbox.Add(""); // faço isso apenas para adicionar uma nova linha na lista
        teste += c.checkbox[i] + "; "; // os valores de c.checkbox[i] retornam "". eu gostaria que retornasse por exemplo 1 ou 0, para eu saber se está marcado ou não.
    }
}
```

**RELEMBRANDO:** Os `names/id's` dos checkbox's do exemplo é: `checkbox0`, `checkbox1`, `checkbox2`.

**EDIT1:** HTML do input checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check0" name="checkbox0">
```

**EDIT2:** Estou fazendo isso pra automatizar, porque se eu fosse fazer manual, seria:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(string checkbox0, string checkbox1, string checkbox2)
{
    var teste += checkbox0 + "; " + checkbox1 + "; " + checkbox2 + ";"; 
}
```

Comment: pode colocar o código de como está gerando a view? se a view for gerada corretamente basta fazer um foreach na property e os valores vão estar lá corretamente

Comment: a view está sendo gerada corretamente, com os names e id's como eu disse. Poderia deixar como ficaria esse foreach em uma resposta ? Pode usar os mesmo name's que usei no exemplo da pergunta @RicardoPontual

Comment: @RicardoPontual deixei como estaria a tag formada na view na pergunta, dê uma olhada

Comment: mas está com o `id` fixo, além disso para passar para a model deve usar `name`.
deve fazer na sua view um `for` para fazer o bind dos itens que tem na model, algo assim: `@for (var i = 0; i < model.checkbox.Count; i++)` e depois algo assim: `<input type="checkbox" asp-for="model[i].checkbox">`

Comment: 1- Eu não posso ter o id fixo, nesse caso ? 2- Não entendi a utilidade do segundo código... Pra que serve esse asp-for? Vai criar os checkbox de acordo com o for? @RicardoPontual

Comment: Eu acho que no meu código `c.checkbox.Add(" ");` eu deveria colocar ao invés de `" "`, o valor que está me retornando do checkbox, só não sei como acessar esse valor.

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua model espera uma coleção de `checkbox` o seu formulário deve fornecer isso para ela. E a maneira como ele vai encontrar esses inputs no`FormData` é através do atributo `name`.

Não está claro, em sua pergunta, como eles estão sendo gerados automaticamente, mas o correto é que eles tenham `id` único e um name que reflita a sua model. No caso `checkbox[0]`, `checkbox[1]`... ou simplesmente `checkbox[]`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo, considerando a model apresentada:

**Model:**

```
public class cl{
    public List<string> checkbox { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

**Formulario.cshtml**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="checkbox[]" value="A"> A <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="checkbox[]" value="B"> B <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="checkbox[]" value="C"> C <br/>    
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Formulario.cshtml.cs**

```
public void OnPost(cl checklist)
{
    var total = checklist.checkbox.Count;
}
```